# $sce.trustAsHtml not working

Tags: angularjs, plaintext, ng-bind-html

I'm getting post content from my REST api.
The content I'm getting: "`&lt;p&gt;test post body&lt;&#x2F;p&gt;`"

first, I'm parsing plain text

```
data[i].postBody = $sce.trustAsHtml(data[i].postBody);
```

after I'm doing this and trying to display with ng-bind-html

```
<span ng-bind-html="value.postBody"></span>
```

and continues displaying as html.

output:

```
<p>test post body</p>
```

I'm not able to show the text without html tags

Please, help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have used htmlDecode function to escape HTML entities first

HTML :

```
<div ng-bind-html="value.postBody"></div>
```

JS :

```
angular.module('ngApp', ['ngSanitize'])
.controller('controller1', ['$scope','$sce', function($scope, $sce) {
    // Some Code ...
    ...
    ...
    function htmlDecode(input) {
        var e = document.createElement('div');
        e.innerHTML = input;
        return e.childNodes.length === 0 ? "" : e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    }
    data[i].postBody = $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlDecode(data[i].postBody));
    ...
    ...
    // Some Code ...
}]);
```

Fiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/3J25M/771/

Comment: Still the same problem :/ I have tried this before, and didnt change anything. Did this work for you?

Comment: Yes this worked for me, let me check in fiddle/plunkr, or share if you have created one

Comment: please check updated answer, i had a `ng-click` event associated so have used the `compile-template` directive also, which is not required in your case, if you want i can keep that too in the answer

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/EGtSLnPekMEDSnsKuAjH?p=preview Here's my problem, check it out!

Comment: The problem is compile-template doesn't make any difference

Comment: OH, man. Thank You! Your function worked for me. U saved my ass broh xD